# Add Regular Expression to Text Element

Tags: xml, relaxng

Is there a way to take an element that is an "anyURI" and add additional constraints such as require "://"?  Or would I have to define a new data type and how would I actually keep the rules for "xsd:anyURI" in that new data type?

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but use a ISO 8601 format date, like XSD dateType. I'm using Jing/Trang to test with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution :

```
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
 <start>
  <ref name="root"/>
 </start>
 <define name="root">
    <element name="root">
        <data type="anyURI" >
            <param name="pattern">.*://.*</param>
        </data>
    </element>
 </define>
</grammar>
```

You can add XML Schema facets using the param attribute.